# React native expo cli installing error:404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

Below error occurred when I tried to install expo cli globally using `npm install -g expo-cli` Can any one help with this ?

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.0: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated iltorb@2.4.5: The zlib module provides APIs for brotli compression/decompression starting with Node.js v10.16.0, please use it over iltorb
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.11.5 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.11.5: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'error-ex@^1.3.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'parse-json'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sanjeewa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T09_09_52_890Z-debug.log
```

Comment: There are some errors going on in the npm registry. 
You can check the status here: https://status.npmjs.org/, it should be solved soon.
Don't install other packages or use other registries to patch that, you will mess things up :)

Answer (score 2):

try this command in your terminal `npm config set registry https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry`

Answer (score 0):

Not your fault. https://registry.npmjs.org/error-ex is down for everyone or not available anymore.

Installing this fixed it for now:

npm i https://github.com/Qix-/node-error-ex