# Why do I get this error when trying to create a React Native app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, init

So I just started using expo last week to learn App development for Android and iOS, and when I first installed Expo and ran ‘expo init test’, I had no problems and easily created the test app where I was able to create some views and buttons and make a simple app. Now today when trying to create another app, I ran `expo init project1` and then when it ran, I got the following error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/errorhandler
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'errorhandler@^1.5.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of '@react-native-community/cli'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alexm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-02-12T15_40_49_482Z-debug.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

I have changed absolutely nothing about my development settings, expo or anything else but now I am getting this error. Why would this happen and how can I fix this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There were some errors going on in the npm registry. Now it's working fine so try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same error [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60187115/react-native-expo-cli-installing-error404-not-found-get-https-registry-npmj). There are some errors going on in the npm registry and I think that issue is solved now.

Answer (score -1):

You should install node module "@react-native-community/cli" to fix it.

> npm i -g @react-native-community/cli